# Was bedeutet "Über den Tellerrand sehen"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Was bedeutet es, wenn man von jemanden sagt,

> dass er nicht über den Tellerrand
>   sieht

oder

> das er noch nicht einmal über den
>   Tellerrand sehen kann

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Redewendung *"über den Tellerrand sehen"* bedeutet im übertragenen Sinne, etwas über den eigenen eingeschränkten Gesichtskreis zu betrachten oder etwas von einer höheren Warte aus zu beobachten.

Somit ist jemand, der nicht über den Tellerrand blickt oder sieht, ein Mensch, der die Dinge nur im seiner engen Umgebung oder in seinen eingeschränktem (herkömmlichen) Denken betrachtet.

Häufig wird der Ausdruck auch als Aufforderung verwendet, die Gegebenheiten und Gebräuche in anderen Ländern und Regionen zu kennenzulernen und offen zu sein für neue oder alternative Methoden.

Beispiele aus Texten:

> "Guck mal über den Tellerrand. Hier interessieren uns Geschichten aus fernen Ländern."
>
> "Über den Tellerrand geschaut: Kehler Studenten engagieren sich für den Verwaltungsaufbau im Kosovo"

Answer (score 4):

An English equivalent would be "to think outside the box".

Comment: Not quite. "To think outside the box" requires unusual cleverness, you don't expect people to think outside the box most of the time. Someone who cannot "über den Tellerrand schauen" is unusually restricted in his outlook. Most people would be between these extremes most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Another English similitude would be:

> To see the bigger picture

It's like extending your own horizon

Answer (score 3):

My best translations into English would be: "Looking beyond the horizon" or "Looking beyond one's own horizon" depending on the context.

I would like to add an observation. Tellerrand (plate's edge) can be seen as a metaphore or simile for the horizon. So I think that 'looking beyond the horizon' (or one's own horizon) might translate "Tellerrand" into english well.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what's been stated so already, it's worthy to note that the original question was using the *negated* term, "[ kann ] **nicht** über den Tellerrand sehen".

In the negative context, the best english equivalent I can come up with would be to say this is used to describe a small-minded person.

It's far more common in German to use the negated "Tellerrand" sentence ("... cannot look beyond the rim of their plate") to call someone small-minded than to use the term "Kleingeist" (the literal translation of "small-mind[ed]").

Comment: Please read: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1050/1487