# Woher kommt die Redewendung "über den Tellerrand sehen"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Hier gibt es die verwandte, aber [abweichende Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/was-bedeutet-ber-den-tellerrand-sehen), was es bedeutet. Das setze ich als bekannt voraus: den Horizont zu erweitern.

Da man aber kein Leberklößchen ist, welches in Suppentellern wohnt, frage ich mich, woher der Ausdruck kommt. Womöglich daher, dass sog. *bessere Familien* ihr Familienwappen auf den Tellerrand malen ließen, bevor der glasiert wurde?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vielleicht eine Frage der Perspektive (apropos Horizont erweitern ;)

Du gehst mit dem Klößchen von etwas aus, das sich im Teller befindet und nicht über den Rand schauen kann.

Wenn aber der Essende selbst gemeint ist, wird es anschaulicher. Die Person konzentriert sich ausschließlich auf ihren Teller (das Essen darauf), schaut nicht uber den Rand hinaus. Sie nimmt also weder weitere Speisen wahr, die aufgetragen wurden, noch beteiligt sie sich am Tischgespräch oder beachtet auch nur die anderen Gäste.

Wenn sie über ihren Tellerrand blickte, sähe sie, was der Tisch noch zu bieten hat.

Answer (score 6):

Auf [redensarten-index.de](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~ueber%20den%20%28eigenen%29%20Tellerrand%20schauen%20%2F%20gucken%20%2F%20blicken%3B%20einen%20Blick%20ueber%20den%20eigenen%20Tellerrand%20werfen&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) wird folgende Hypothese vertreten:

> [Diese Redensart] ist nach 1970 entstanden und könnte nach Küpper(*) vom Bundeswirtschaftsminister Karl Schiller geprägt worden sein. In seinem Kündigungsschreiben an Bundeskanzler Brandt 1972 kritisiert er dessen seiner Meinung nach zu starke Orientierung an der Demoskopie: "Die Regierung hat die Pflicht, über den Tellerrand des Wahltermins hinauszublicken und dem Volke rechtzeitig zu sagen, was zu leisten und was zu fordern ist. Diese von mir mehrfach empfohlene Strategie ist bisher im Kabinett nicht einmal andiskutiert, geschweige denn akzeptiert."

Ich habe im Archiv des SPIEGEL, der ZEIT und des Hamburger Abendblatts keine Verwendung der Redensart vor 1972 gefunden, dafür aber zumindest im SPIEGEL Treffer für fast alle Folgejahre. [Dieses Interview](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-42891180.html), offenbar mit einem Kandidaten für Schillers Nachfolge, verwendet den Ausdruck gleich zweimal und ist der älteste Beleg für die Redewendung im Spiegel-Archiv.

Auch dieses Ngram legt nahe, dass diese Redewendung um diese Zeit in Gebrauch gekommen ist:

[image: Google Ngram für "über den Tellerrand"]
<sup>[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22%C3%BCber%20den%20tellerrand%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2015&corpus=20&smoothing=3)</sup>

Das macht die oben genannte Hypothese, dass es sich um eine Schöpfung von Karl Schiller handelt, in meinen Augen zumindest plausibel.

[Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23/takkat) hat dankenswerterweise darauf hingewiesen, dass [in einem Buch von Arno Scholz](https://books.google.de/books?id=aPY7AAAAMAAJ&q=%22bis+zum+eigenen+Tellerrand%22&dq=%22bis+zum+eigenen+Tellerrand&redir_esc=y) bereits 1953 der Begriff *Tellerand* als Metapher für einen engen Horizont verwendet wurde:

> So ist es auch jetzt wieder; ein großer Teil der Deutschen sieht wiederum nur bis zum eigenen Tellerrand.

Möglicherweise wurde Schiller davon inspiriert. Da ich ansonsten keine anderen Belege aus dieser Zeit finden konnte, halte ich es für eher unwahrscheinlich, dass die Metapher damals bereits allgemein in Gebrauch war.

Außerdem möchte ich darauf hinweisen, dass der Begriff *Tellerrand* auch noch anders gedeutet werden kann denn als Teil eines Essgeschirrs (**). Der flache "Deckel" einer Mütze, insbesondere einer [Schirmmütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schirmm%C3%BCtze) wie der beim Militär getragenen [Tellermütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellerm%C3%BCtze), der [Studentenmütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentenm%C3%BCtze), der [Schiffermütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schifferm%C3%BCtze) oder der [Prinz-Heinrich-Mütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prinz-Heinrich-M%C3%BCtze), heißt *Teller*. In Österreich nennt man diese Mützen laut Wikipedia deswegen sogar *Tellermützen*. Der Rand des Mützentellers ist dann natürlich der Tellerrand, wie zu sehen an der [hier](http://www.abendblatt.de/archiv/1956/article202919613/Spesen-klein-geschrieben.html) zitierten Bundeswehr-Verordnung

> Die Mützen werden "ohne den Mützendraht im inneren Tellerrand getragen".

Solche Mützen wurden zu Scholz' und Schillers Zeiten noch weitaus häufiger getragen als heute - durchaus möglich, dass damit auch die Bedeutung *Mützendeckel* für *Teller* noch geläufiger war.

Ja, und wessen Blick nicht weiter reicht als der Teller seiner Mütze, der hat wirklich einen sehr engen Horizont.

(*) Küpper, Heinz: Wörterbuch der deutschen Umgangssprache
(**) Ich möchte es wirklich als *kann* verstanden wissen. Ich halte diese Hypothese selbst für deutlich unwahrscheinlicher.

Comment: das mit dem *Mützendeckel* gefällt mir auch gut.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Antwort geht leicht ins Spekulative, aber ich schlage folgende Interpretation vor:

Für lange Zeit wurde die Welt als flache Scheibe oder Teller angesehen. Die Entdeckungsreise nach Amerika glich einem Sprung über den Tellerrand ins Unbekannte und möglicherweise nicht Existente. Entsprechend gleicht der Ausdruck einem *thinking outside the box* insofern, als man sich jenseits von sicheren Wahrheiten wagt.

Comment: Bereits in der Antike beobachtete man, dass von Schiffen am Horizont der Rumpf verschwand, während der Mast mit Segel sichtbar blieb. Auch die Sichelform des Halbmondes wurde richtig mit kugelförmigen Himmelskörpern in Zusammenhang gebracht. Zwar gibt es in der Bibel eine Stelle, da der Teufel Jesus versucht, und auf einen Berg führt, der so hoch ist, dass man die ganze Welt überblicken kann - die Zivilisation, die dieses Stück Text produzierte war also nicht auf der Höhe der Zeit; die Verfasser nicht die hellsten. Dass diese aber auf die dt. Sprache Einfluß hatten?

Comment: Die Menschheit in ihrer Gesamtheit hat niemals daran geglaubt, die Welt sei eine flache Scheibe. Das ist ein Mythos.

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Ach ja? Woher sollten richtig alte Kulturen wissen, dass das nicht so war? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flache_Erde. Die Menschheit in ihrer Gesamtheit hat viellecht hat schon lange nicht mehr daran geglaubt, aber *niemals*?

Answer (score 0):

Die Antwort von John Smithers enthält schon den richtigen Ausgangspunkt, geht mir aber nicht weit genug.

Der, der (nicht) über den Tellerrand blickt, ist tatsächlich der Esser. Er hat das im Blickfeld, was ihn unmittelbar betrifft, nämlich seinen Teller und dessen Inhalt. Und es stimmt auch, dass damit gemeint ist, dass sich jemand, der nicht über den Rand seines Tellers blickt, sich um nichts kümmert, was sich außerhalb des Tellers befindet.

Damit ist aber nur sehr bedingt die nähere Umgebung des Tellers (andere Speisen, Personen rund um den Tisch) gemeint. Denn auch jemand, der nur den Tisch und dessen unmittelbare Umgebung erfasst, ist im Sinne des Sprichworts jemand, der nicht über den Tellerrand blickt.

Jemand, der über den Tellerrand blickt, interessiert sich auch für Dinge, die wesentlich weiter als ein, zwei Armlängen entfernt sind:

- Woher kommt das Essen, das da auf dem Teller liegt?
- Was ist außerhalb des Zimmers, in dem der Tisch steht?
- Gibt es andere Speisen als die, die gerade am Tisch bereitstehen?
- Was ist außerhalb des Hauses? Außerhalb der Stadt?
- Was beschäftigt die Menschen in anderen Ländern?
- Welche Sorgen hat man am anderen Ende der Welt?

Der, der über den Tellerrand blickt, interessiert sich nicht nur für seine Außenwelt, sondern er interessiert sich auch für seine eigene Rolle, die er »*da draußen*« spielt:

- Was passiert mit der Welt, wenn ich Rindfleisch esse, und was passiert, wenn ich Feldfrüchte esse?
- Welche Auswirkungen hat es, wenn ich bei der nächsten politischen Wahl mein Kreuz bei X statt bei Y mache?
- Was kann ich tun, um zu verhindern, dass das Land, auf dem heute Millionen Menschen wohnen, in 50 Jahren nicht Teil des Meeresbodens wird?

Darum geht es beim *Blick über den Tellerrand*. Nicht um Tischgespräche und andere Speisen.

Comment: "Darum geht es beim _Blick über den Tellerrand_." - Auch wenn ich Dir inhaltlich durchaus zustimmen kann - worum es bei dem Ausdruck geht, ist nicht hier gefragt, sondern [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/was-bedeutet-ber-den-tellerrand-sehen). Ich finde schon John Smithers Antwort grenzwertig, aber da könnte man noch sagen, dass er überlegt, was den Ausdruck motiviert haben könnte. Deine Antwort geht dann aber eindeutig in Richtung Interpretation, nicht Herkunft.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre folgender Ansatz zur Quelle dieser umgangssprachlichen Umschreibung für ein zu engstirniges Denken oder Handeln:

Charles-Maurice de Talleyrand-Périgord (Ehemaliger Französischer Minister für auswärtige Angelegenheiten und internationale Entwicklung) könnte mit seinem Weitblick der Ursprung der Formulierung sein.

Und das mit einer Aussage zu einer Handlung seines Dienstherren Napoleon, als dieser 1804 den nach Baden geflohenen Bourbonen-Herzog von Enghien zurück nach Frankreich verschleppen und umbringen ließ.

Dazu meinte Talleyrand: "Es ist schlimmer als ein Verbrechen. Es ist ein Fehler."